# Setup global Http request Headers on angular dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How can I configure the Http service adding headers to the call.

I try the following

```dart
class GlobalHttpHeaders {
  static setup(Injector inj){
    HttpDefaultHeaders http = inj.get(HttpDefaultHeaders);
    http.setHeaders([{"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}], "COMMON");
  }
}
```

And in the app the last line is:

```dart
Injector inj = ngBootstrap(module: new SiteIceiModule());
  GlobalHttpHeaders.setup(inj);
```

But that don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I think) I got it working with:

```dart
@Injectable()
class MyDefaultHeaders extends HttpDefaultHeaders {
  @override
  setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers, String method) {
    super.setHeaders(headers, method);
    //if(method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') {
    headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    //}
  }
}


@NgComponent(selector: 'my-comp', publishAs: 'ctrl', template:
    '<div>My component</div>')
class MyComponent {
  Http http;
  MyComponent(this.http) {
    //http.request('http://www.google.com/');
    var h = http;
        // debugger didn't show http so I filed https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17486

    Map m = {};
    http.defaults.headers.setHeaders(m, 'GET');
    print(m);
    // prints:
    // {Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*, X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest}

  }
}


class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {

    type(MyComponent);

    type(HttpDefaultHeaders, implementedBy: MyDefaultHeaders);

    init.createParser(this);
  }
}
```

I couldn't examine `http` to verify the headers because the debugger didn't show me the field but as stated in the comment
when I apply `headers.setHeaders` do a map inside `MyComponent` I get my custom header (this is what `Http` does with `headers`)
I used `DI 0.0.33`, `Angular 0.9.9`

Comment: The above example was not working in Angular v12 because it needed the `@Injectable()` on the MyDefaultHeaders.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the discussion, but the answer provided was not usable for me, as my http requests are made by a 3rd party library. But I figured out a way to change the default headers.

You can access and modify the HttpDefaultHeaders object like a map.

```
headers['Common'].addAll({'Authorization': 'Basic $auth', 'X-Testing': 'Testing'});
```

This also works with 3rd Party libraries like hammock.

Note: I used angular 1.1.1 I don't know in which version this was added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```dart
class SiteIceiModule extends Module { 
  SiteIceiModule() {
    // ...
    factory(HttpDefaultHeaders, (inj) => inj.get(HttpDefaultHeaders)..setHeader({...}));
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have. It seems setHeader is not to set the headers of the HttpDefaultHeaders class but is called by HttpRequest (or how the Angular specific class is named) to get the headers in HttpDefaultHeaders set to itself. There is no way to modify the default headers configured in HttpDefaultHeaders. I tried to make DI to inject a custom class that implements that interface but DI seems to prevent the type configured by Angular to be overridden by AppModule. It is of cource possible that I made some mistake, but I invested quite some time.

Comment: This example results in `Illegal argument(s): Cannot resolve a circular dependency! (resolving BlockCache -> Http -> HttpDefaults -> HttpDefaultHeaders -> HttpDefaultHeaders)`